# Filtering Data From Scraped Tweets Using rtweet Package

Tags: filtering, screen-scraping, rtweet

```
meta_mueller <- search_tweets("mueller", n = 250000, retryonratelimit = TRUE)
```

Within the dataframe is a column "geo_coords". A majority upon visual scan are c(NA,NA).

I have dplyr installed (other packages are fine, too) and I want to identify any rows that do not equal c(NA,NA).

```
filter(!is.na(meta_mueller(geo_coords))
```

This did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
meta_mueller_location = select(meta_mueller, place_full_name)

meta_mueller_location_filter = filter(meta_mueller_location, 
 place_full_name != "NA")
```

Instead of geo_coords I used the command on "place_full_name" column which was only NA not c(NA,NA). This was a better solution for my needs.